# How to put divider between few of list items in ListView.separated

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to put google ads after specific number of items list or in between the items list in [`ListView.separated`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html).

I have attached an image to make it clear how I want to do it:

[image]

> Source of the image is: [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-listview-and-scrollphysics-a-detailed-look-7f0912df2754)

Comment: I really do not get the question here...

Comment: I want to add google ads in between item list in listview, please look at the example in the image attached.

Comment: so add it as list a regular list item, not as divider

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, I believe, you need to install a library to display Google AdMob ads. For instance - [`admob_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter) lib.

Then you only need to set up the `separatorBuilder` property of your `ListView.separated` widget.

e.g.

```dart
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: 25,
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (index % 5 == 0) { // Display `AdmobBanner` every 5 'separators'.
      return AdmobBanner(
        adUnitId: /* AdMob Unit ID */,
        adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
      );
    }
    return Divider();
  },
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('item $index'),
    );
  },
)
```

This code is only an example, you might encounter Infinite Height layout errors as I am not aware of how `admob_flutter` widgets operate.

However, this should be enough to get you started with your idea.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but unfortunately it didn't work as it was supposed to.

Comment: Solution is copy-paste from Flutter documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html